# Laravel 10 - How to display an object-generated raw SQL query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

Laravel 10 - How to display an object-generated raw SQL query?

```
        $validatedData = $request->validated();
        // Save the application settings
        $settings = new AppSettings();
        $settings->application_name = $validatedData['application_name'];
        $settings->footer_text = $validatedData['footer_text'];
        $settings->where('id',1);
        $settings->update();
        /* How to show the Raw SQL query of this $settings object? */
        
        return response()->json([
            'message' => __('app.record_saved_successfully'),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  We do not know what type of object AppSettings is?